# multiple cURL requests to Magento

Tags: php, magento, curl, cookies

I have to send 3 requests to a Magento website with cURL. The first two are dedicated to create the cookie and make it roams in the website, and the third one is dedicated to send message via POST method to the contact form.
The problem is the requests do not seem to work.
Here is the PHP code and the curl request infos will follow :

```
    <?php

/*
 * On va effectuer 3 requêtes cURL afin de créer le cookie et de 
 * le balader dans le site distant. Une fois le cookie enrichie 
 * par les 2 premières requêtes, on envoi les données en POST
 * au formulaire de contact.
 */

//var_dump($_POST);

//Données
$url = $_POST['url'];
$name = $_POST['msg'][0];
$email = $_POST['msg'][1];
$telephone = $_POST['msg'][2];
$comment = $_POST['msg'][3];
$hideit = '';

//Formatage données formulaire
$curl_datas = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'telephone' => $telephone,
    'comment' => $comment,
    'hideit' => $hideit
);
$curl_datas = http_build_query($curl_datas);

//Gestion Cookie
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
if(!file_exists(realpath($cookie)))
    touch($cookie); // Si le cookie n'existe pas on le crée


//// Première requête ////

//Initialisation de la connexion
$curl_connection = curl_init($url);

//Définition des options

//Header de la requête
$req_header[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$req_header[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate';
$req_header[] = 'Accept-Language:fr,en;q=0.8';
$req_header[] = 'Cache-Control:no-cache';
$req_header[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
$req_header[] = 'Host:'.str_replace('/','',str_replace('http://','',$url));
$req_header[] = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 YaBrowser/14.12.2125.10034 Safari/537.36';

//CURL options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $req_header);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25); //limite de temps pour la connexion
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //True permet de renvoyer la réponse sous forme de string dans une variable
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //False permet de ne pas retourner d'erreur en cas de connexion SSL non valide
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //Sur 1 pour suivre la redirection "Location" du header de la page distante
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie)); // On sauvegarde le cookie

//Exécution de la requête
$result1 = curl_exec($curl_connection);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
curl_close($curl_connection);


//// Deuxième requête ////
// On enrichie notre cookie avec la page contact

$curl_connection = curl_init($url.'contact/');

$req_header[] = 'Referer:'.$url; // On dit qu'on vient de la page d'accueil afin de leurer magento.

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $req_header);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25); //limite de temps pour la connexion
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //True permet de renvoyer la réponse sous forme de string dans une variable
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //False permet de ne pas retourner d'erreur en cas de connexion SSL non valide
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //Sur 1 pour suivre la redirection "Location" du header de la page distante
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie)); // On sauvegarde le cookie

$result2 = curl_exec($curl_connection);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
curl_close($curl_connection);

//// Troisième requête ////
// On envoi les données au formulaire de contact

$curl_connection = curl_init($url.'contact/index/post/');

$req_header2[] ='Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$req_header2[] ='Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate';
$req_header2[] ='Accept-Language:fr,en;q=0.8';
$req_header2[] ='Cache-Control:no-cache';
$req_header2[] ='Connection:keep-alive';
$req_header2[] ='Host:'.str_replace('/','',str_replace('http://','',$url));
$req_header2[] ='Origin:'.$url;
$req_header2[] ='Referer:'.$url.'contact/'; // On dit qu'on vient du formulaire.
$req_header2[] ='User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 YaBrowser/14.12.2125.10034 Safari/537.36';

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $req_header2);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25); //limite de temps pour la connexion
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //True permet de renvoyer la réponse sous forme de string dans une variable
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //False permet de ne pas retourner d'erreur en cas de connexion SSL non valide
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //Sur 1 pour suivre la redirection "Location" du header de la page distante
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true); // On va envoyer du POST
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_datas); // On envoie les champs du formulaire initial
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie)); // On sauvegarde le cookie

$result3 = curl_exec($curl_connection);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
curl_close($curl_connection);

//var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo json_encode($result3);
echo $result1 . $result2 . $result3;

?>
```

and the request responses :

```
array (size=27)
  'url' => string 'https://www.venroy.com.au/?SID=pp0j3808nggc4kn7idor5843o3' (length=57)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 302
  'header_size' => int 6930
  'request_size' => int 5016
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 19
  'redirect_count' => int 10
  'total_time' => float 5.943
  'namelookup_time' => float 5.522
  'connect_time' => float 5.522
  'pretransfer_time' => float 5.522
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 25
  'speed_download' => float 4
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 25
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 5.943
  'redirect_time' => float 5.522
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '54.79.75.34' (length=11)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string '192.168.1.53' (length=12)
  'local_port' => int 52650
  'request_header' => string 'GET /?SID=pp0j3808nggc4kn7idor5843o3 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=pp0j3808nggc4kn7idor5843o3
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:fr,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:https:www.venroy.com.au
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 YaBrowser/14.12.2125.10034 Safari/537.36

' (length=463)
array (size=27)
  'url' => string 'https://www.venroy.com.au/contact/?SID=tgqcahsh306nkhgfbp60hinbj1' (length=65)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 302
  'header_size' => int 7018
  'request_size' => int 5500
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 19
  'redirect_count' => int 10
  'total_time' => float 5.897
  'namelookup_time' => float 5.492
  'connect_time' => float 5.492
  'pretransfer_time' => float 5.492
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 25
  'speed_download' => float 4
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 25
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 5.897
  'redirect_time' => float 5.492
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '54.79.75.34' (length=11)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string '192.168.1.53' (length=12)
  'local_port' => int 52676
  'request_header' => string 'GET /contact/?SID=tgqcahsh306nkhgfbp60hinbj1 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=tgqcahsh306nkhgfbp60hinbj1
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:fr,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:https:www.venroy.com.au
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 YaBrowser/14.12.2125.10034 Safari/537.36
Referer:https://www.venroy.com.au/

' (length=507)
array (size=27)
  'url' => string 'https://www.venroy.com.au/contact/index/?SID=232knnhjjng7i8aelj17h4u0p6' (length=71)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 302
  'header_size' => int 7324
  'request_size' => int 7006
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 19
  'redirect_count' => int 10
  'total_time' => float 6.147
  'namelookup_time' => float 5.725
  'connect_time' => float 5.725
  'pretransfer_time' => float 5.725
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 25
  'speed_download' => float 4
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 25
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 6.147
  'redirect_time' => float 5.725
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '54.79.75.34' (length=11)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string '192.168.1.53' (length=12)
  'local_port' => int 52677
  'request_header' => string 'GET /contact/index/?SID=232knnhjjng7i8aelj17h4u0p6 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=232knnhjjng7i8aelj17h4u0p6; message_box_display=1; private_content_version=3d6eea71bd829b652b11e871ab617fbf
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:fr,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:https:www.venroy.com.au
Origin:https://www.venroy.com.au/
Referer:https://www.venroy.com.au/contact
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Win'... (length=636)
false
```

Thank to everyone if you can help me to understand the requests responses, and why it return false, and so doesnt seem to work.

Have a good day :)

Edit : I think that I have a redirect loop for allmy requests, because curl error return 47. How can I avoid it ? Thank you

Comment: Why are you closing curl each time? That's a waste of your time, having to reinitialize curl every single time to the same settings. you can use ONE curl instances to do all of those requests, changing only the settings necessary each time.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about why the requests don't work?  Does it return false when you expect true or are you encountering an error/warning message?  If so, can you include it?

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. It seems to have a 302 response when I expect a 200 and it returns false I don't know why. I'm not at ease using cookies and I'm not sure if it's correctly set. Also if you look in the var dump, the url seems to be incomplete (it's not the /post/ in the url in the last request). Thank you. I'm also looking for an external magento contact form to make some tests if some of you gt one. Thank you very much